# How to use ZF2 ZendPdf in Yii Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, yii, zend-framework2, zend-pdf

I want to parse a PDF document in my project, I'm using Yii framework and I'm able to load ZendFramework 1.12, actually I'm using Zend_Lucene and Zend_Mail successfully, but ZendPdf fails to parse the PDF, so I wanted to try with ZF2 (ZendFramework 2), but I'm not able to make it work... I just downloaded the ZF2 library and added the following to my base Controller:

```
public function __construct($id,$module=null){
    Yii::import('application.vendors.ZendFramework.library.*');
    Yii::setPathOfAlias('Zend',Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.ZendFramework.library.Zend'));
    parent::__construct($id,$module);
}
```

So every time I use a Controller this code is executed. Then in the controller I have:

```
use ZendPdf\PdfDocument;
use Zend\Mail;
class AjaxController extends Controller{...

...
public function actionTestPdf(){    
    $filepath = realpath('./path/').'/pdftest2.pdf';
    $pdf = PdfDocument::load($filepath);
}
```

When I run the controller: /ajax/TestPdf
I get: Fatal error: Class 'ZendPdf\PdfDocument' not found

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to install your ZF2 stuff with composer and [include the autoloader from composer](https://github.com/phundament/app/blob/master/www/index.php#L13) to get PSR compatible autoloading.

Alternative 1)
You may also try pointing an `alias` `ZendPdf\PdfDocument` to the class file location.

Alternative 2)
`import` the needed classes or directories in your application config.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I would recommend NOT using ZendPdf from ZF2, because it is functionally equivalent to Zend_Pdf from ZF1 and so all you're going to do is add unnecessary complexity with classloading, etc, but not solve your underlying problem, as the document will still most likely NOT load using ZendPdf from ZF2.

You should investigate the underlying reason why the document is failing to load in ZF1.